# F# Equivalent of Python range

Tags: python, f#

I've started learning F#, and one thing I've run into is I don't know any way to express the equivalent of the `range` function in Python. I know `[1..12]` is the equivalent of range(1,13). But what I want to be able to do is `range(3, 20, 2)` (I know Haskell has `[3,5..19]`). How can I express this?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=f%23+range+with+step) seems to [indicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx) that it's `3..2..20`. I'm not an F# guy, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @GuyCoder `range` returns a list in Python 2.x; in Python 3 it returns a `range` object,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
seq { 3 .. 2 .. 20 }
```

results in

```
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx

Answer (score 5):

While the F# [sequence expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) `seq { 3 .. 2 .. 20 }` is comparable in functionality if you have ever converted Python to F# you will find that the

- Python 2 [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) method returns a Python [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) which is mutable.
- Python 3 [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) method returns a Python [range type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) which represents an immutable sequence of numbers.
- F# sequence expression returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which is immutable.

The better way to interpret a Python range with regards to F# is to look at how it is often used. As the Python 2 documentation states

> It is most often used in for loops.

and the Python 3 documentation states

> is commonly used for looping a specific number of times in for loops.

and the Python 2 [for](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
```

and the Python 3 [for](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

```
for i in range(5):
...     print(i)
```

The closest F# is [for in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx):

```
for i in 10 .. -1 .. 1 do
    printf "%d " i
```

Comment: Ranges are immutable in Python 3.

Comment: As a second hint, in Python 2 `xrange` is the preferred efficient `range` object that has the same immutable qualities. The fact that it's preferred, but not obvious, was presumably a drive for the Python 3.X implementation. There were a lot of other similar changes the `map` function returning a `map` object would be a great example. Also, `reduce` was moved back to the `functools` standard library package.

Comment: What would you do in F# if you wanted a different step size? Equivalent to Python Range(0,10,2) as an example

Comment: @Nulle That is answered in both answers; e.g. `seq { 3 .. 2 .. 20 }` or `for i in 10 .. -1 .. 1 do`